# Application bundle with dylib

Tags: c++, xcode, dylib

ALL,

First of all every question on the topic are about deployment the ready to use application. My situation is different.

I am developing the application on Mac with Xcode 5.1.1 (meaning I'm still writing code) with C++. My application contains the main binary executable (which is set as Cocoa bundle application) and couple of dylib libraries (which I'm writing and have control over).

The trouble comes from the fact that at some point I would like to test my code. My project for the main application in the "Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries" references the libraries the binary uses and the dylib's have their dependencies there.

Now when I'm trying to call dlopen, the call fails because the dylib files can not be found.

So my questions are:

1. Should dylib files be stored in the bundle?
2. If yes - how do I put them there? Because I presume that whatever I did is not enough.
3. If not - what is the correct way of testing the code?

Thank you for any information you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The Dylibs are not stored in the app bundle but they are compiled with the app and are included with the binary executable, to include them just add them to **Target Dependencies** and **Link With Libraries** in "Build Phases" there is no need for dlopen

and include the headers like:

```
#include "Dylib.h"
```

Comment: first, not sure what you mean by saying "no need for dlopen"? I called a function in the library by doing "dlopen/dlsym. Second - there is no "#import". Only "#include". Did you miss "C++" tag? Also as I said - "I'm still doing development" and this is for the testing purposes.

Comment: sorry for import, what i mean with no need for dlopen that the OS will take care of linking the library and all the symbols "aka function names and constants"

Comment: OK, but that mean it will statically link my dylib, which defeats the purpose of creating it in the first place.

Comment: if you want to copy the with app bundle goto **Build Phases** and add **Copy Files** and select destination to Frameworks and add all Dylibs

Comment: It's not that I want to. My question is - what is OSX native way of dealing with this situation? Are dylibs usually stored inside the bundle? Especially during the development and testing stages.

Comment: they are usually embedded inside executable and she times when they are not embedded and copied to frameworks folder in app bundle OS X will also do all the linking